# Can I display the list of all the system objects (semaphores, queues...) in VxWorks?

Tags: vxworks

I would like to know what semaphores, messageQueues, etc... are active in my vxWorks 6.x system. I have access to this information via the debugger, but I would like access to it from the shell.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VxWorks 6.x provides a function called classShow() which will list all the objects of a specific class (e.g. semaphores, message queues, tasks, ...).
The following call will give you a list of objects for a given class:

```
classShow(objClassIdGet(classId), 1) 

The classId types are:
  1  windSemClass,       /* Wind native semaphore */
  2  windSemPxClass,     /* POSIX semaphore */
  3  windMsgQClass,      /* Wind native message queue */
  4  windMqPxClass,      /* POSIX message queue */
  5  windRtpClass,       /* real time process */
  6  windTaskClass,      /* task */
  7  windWdClass,        /* watchdog */
  8  windFdClass,        /* file descriptor */
  9  windPgPoolClass,    /* page pool */
  10 windPgMgrClass,     /* page manager */
  11 windGrpClass,       /* group */
  12 windVmContextClass, /* virtual memory context */
  13 windTrgClass,       /* trigger */
  14 windMemPartClass,   /* memory partition */
  15 windI2oClass,       /* I2O */
  16 windDmsClass,       /* device management system */
  17 windSetClass,       /* Set */
  18 windIsrClass,       /* ISR object */
  19 windTimerClass,     /* Timer services */
  20 windSdClass,        /* Shared data region */
  21 windPxTraceClass,   /* POSIX trace */
```